# If any user sticks more than 20 second in my website ,Contact form pop up should ask to fill the details

Tags: jquery, css, forms, sidebar

If any user sticks more than 20s in my website ,Contact form should come and pop up should ask to fill the details,I want this form should be in right sidebar(like vertical position).so again I am telling if any user just waiting in website for 20s , this pop up should come. Now i am facing  issue in toggle function also not showing to me and further i want to implement 30 second code, can any one guide me in that, form should be responsive one. here is the link please check

http://lotusvalue.in/popup.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    alert('ok1');
    $(".pop−content").toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.pop-content {
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 60px;
  right: 20px;
  display: none;
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 300px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pop-content">
  <form>
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
<button>Enquiry form</button>
```

Comment: Now I want to know how to make the enquiry  form button vertical and better appearance of look and feel like this,I make form fields because it should be responsive form , i am stuck with css part of vertical side bar and popup look and feel

Comment: your answer is correct. but i am unable to give tick symbol, Now I want to know how to make the enquiry form button vertical and better appearance of look and feel like this,I make form fields because it should be responsive form

Comment: if you update later also not a problem, once you finish please updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display: none;` from `.pop-content` class, then try with below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pop-content").toggle();
      $("button").click(function(){
          $(".pop-content").toggle(1000);
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".pop-content").toggle(1000);
      }, 30000);

  });
```

Comment: it's correct, but if u see my enquiry button it is horizontal and i want that to be in  vertical sidebar  like this | , could you do this?

Comment: `-moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);` Write this code in `button` css, I hope it will help to rotate button

Comment: great aquib, Now see the form design , i think it is not responsive, I can add more fileds in form not a problem, For responsive form what i have to add there, first time making this task that why,  can you do that and with some color combination also for look and feel for ex : https://www.formget.com/how-to-design-sidebar-sliding-contact-form-with-javascript/

Comment: are you there ,we have completed 90 percentage , please help me , i have to complete this work, next time i will update my knowledge , my company immediate assign the task

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183704/discussion-between-aquib-iqbal-and-kaviya).

Answer (score 0):

To display your form 30 seconds after the page opens you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".pop−content").toggle(1000);
  }, 30000);
});
```

Comment: Now I want to know how to make the enquiry form button vertical and better appearance of look and feel like this,I make form fields because it should be responsive form , i am stuck with css part of vertical side bar and popup look and feel

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('.pop-content').slideToggle();
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.pop-content').slideToggle();
  },30000);/*30 seconds delay*/
});
```

```css
.pop-content {
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 60px;
  right: 20px;
  display: none;
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 300px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pop-content">
  <form>
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
<button>Enquiry form</button>
```

Comment: Now I want to know how to make the enquiry form button vertical and better appearance of look and feel like this,I make form fields because it should be responsive form , i am stuck with css part of vertical side bar and popup look and feel

Comment: You can do it with pinch of css transform: rotateZ(-90deg); to the button and you're all set.

Comment: it showing in horizontal only like this  ======== not in |